# Possible to play Windows Media Center recorded tv (dvr-ms) on OSX w/o conversion?

Tags: macos, windows-vista, windows-media-center, htpc, dvr-ms

I have an HTPC running Windows Vista Media Center, and use it quite heavily to record TV. I have a Macbook I use for work that I'd like to be able to have TV on during those late night coding sessions. Sure, I can pick it up and take it to the couch in front of the TV, but that doesn't work so well if my wife wants to watch something else, and I can't use my external display.

Many sites reference to tools but they won't play WMC's dvr-ms without conversion. It would be more trouble to convert than to just move into the other room.

Does anyone know of software for OSX (preferably free, but I'll pay a nominal fee) that will play dvr-ms recorded TV directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) will play my Recorded TV directly off the HTPC's Samba share. The quality isn't as good, but I didn't expect it to work anyway. It's "good enough" for my needs, though.

Other references I found about VLC for this said conversion is necessary, but not with version 1.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this particular type of file, but you might want to try [Perian](http://perian.org/).  If you're not familiar, it's a QuickTime Player add-on that adds the ability to play all sorts of files.